# Decent Knights - Chess

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, optimization, chess

In [Naughty knights](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/naughty-knights) it’s asked to prove that it’s impossible to fit more than 32 knights such that no knight attacking other.

Can you find the minimum number of knights, filling the table in a way that fitting any other knight is impossible unless two attacking each other.

Comment: Are you asking for solution in which none of the knights attack another knight? (The minimal knight covering can be easily found online, but does not have such restriction.)

Comment: Spoiler: [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23258/what-is-the-least-number-of-knights-needed-to-cover-the-entire-board) on chess.SE has solutions that do not prohibit attacking occupied squares.

Comment: @DanielMathias Both of those linked solutions contain attacking pairs.

Comment: @RobPratt As I stated.

Comment: @DanielMathias OK, so by "Spoiler" you meant that the first solution provides a lower bound?

Comment: @RobPratt This question, as stated, does not explicitly prohibit attacking pairs. Unless it is clarified that this restriction is intended, the first solution is optimal.

Comment: OEIS [A342576](https://oeis.org/A342576) contains the answers for NxN board (the count and one configuration per size for sizes <= 14). The example for 8x8 is the same as RobPratt's solution.

Answer (score 5):

If the placed knights also cannot attack each other, you are asking for the [independent domination number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Independent_domination) of the [knight's graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_graph) that has a node for each cell and an edge for each pair of cells that are a knight's move apart.  Via integer linear programming with a binary decision variable for each cell, the minimum turns out to be

> 14:

> [image]

Comment: You could have made it symmetrical with C1 to A2 or H7 to F8.

Comment: Yes, and it turns out that there are eight 180-degree rotationally symmetric solutions.